# memory error with itertools when parallelizing for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to parallelize a for loop in python. I get a memory error in the permutations phase of the parameters.

I can see why this might fail, but what is the other way to do the same thing.

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing
LOAD_GEN_KEYS = range(138259)
ES_DATA_K = range(9606834)
paramlist      = list(itertools.product(LOAD_GEN_KEYS, ES_DATA_K))
pool           = multiprocessing.Pool()
VALID_TS       = pool.map(curate_results, paramlist)


def curate_results(params):
    LG = params[0]
    ES = params[1]
    ES_S = str(int(ES)/1000)
    if ES_S == LG:
        return [LG, ES]
    else:
        return []
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a list of 138259 * 9606834 items.  That is too much for your memory.

I propose to go with the generator which `itertools.product()` actually is (i. e. the elements aren't stored in memory but created on the fly during iterating):

```
paramlist      = itertools.product(LOAD_GEN_KEYS, ES_DATA_K)
```

Since the `pool.map(curate_results, paramlist)` accepts an iterable, a generator should do as fine as the list.

Comment: looks like even doing that doesn't help it. should I do it in chunks instead?

Comment: `    VALID_TS       = pool.map(curate_results, paramlist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 304, in map_async
    iterable = list(iterable)
MemoryError` Here is the error

Comment: You are aware that you are mapping 1.3 trillion combinations, right?  Where do you expect the results to be stored?

Comment: that's true again. don't think my dram is large enough to store all this..

Comment: The question rather is:  Is what you are doing even a sound approach?  I mean, why do you combine each LOAD_GEN_KEYS with each ES_DATA_K?

Comment: I think that's the valid question. I need to ponder on this for a while.